# How can I get a different set of objects from an array for each accordion item?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, accordion, array.prototype.map

So currently all three of my accordion items have the same set of objects, which is not what I want. I want to have 3 different set for each. Here's what I've tried so far, which doesn't work obviously:

```
    const meetingRooms = [
      {
        name: ["title-1", "title-2", "title-3"],
        title: "Project1",
        value: ["item-1", "item-2", "item-3"],
        date: "2021-12-19 17:18:00",
        content: "Example content",
        contentValue: ["content1", "content2", "content3"]
      },
      {
        name: ["second-title-1", "second-title-2", "second-title-3"],
        title: "Project2",
        value: ["item-4", "item-5", "item-6"],
        content: "Example content1",
        date: "2021-12-19 17:18:00",
        contentValue: [{val1:"more content1", val2:"more content1", val3:"more content1"}, {val1:"more content2", val2:"more content2" ,val3:"more content2"}, {val1:"more content3", val2:"more content3", val3:"more content3"}]
      },
      {
        name: ["third-title-1", "third-title-2", "third-title-3"],
        title: "Project3",
        value: ["item-7", "item-8", "item-9"],
        content: "Example content",
        date: "2021-12-19 17:18:00",
        contentValue: ["surprise content1", "surprise content2", "surprise content3"]
      }
    ];


 {meetingRooms.map((m) => (
            <NotificationColumn>
              <Header>
                  {m.name}
              </Header>
              <Accordion
                type="single"
                collapsible
              >
                {m.value.map((v, idx)=>
                <AccordionItem value={m.value[idx]}>
                  <AccordionTrigger>{m.name[idx]}</AccordionTrigger>
                  {m.contentValue.map((v, idx)=>
                  <AccordionContent  key={idx}>
                    {m.contentValue[idx]}
                  </AccordionContent>
                  )}
                </AccordionItem>
                )}

              </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring v and idx on the second loop, that's why it's stuck mixing indexes

Your code:

```
{m.value.map((v, idx)=>
    <AccordionItem value={m.value[idx]}>
        <AccordionTrigger>{m.name[idx]}</AccordionTrigger>
            {m.contentValue.map((v, idx)=>
                <AccordionContent  key={idx}>
                    {m.contentValue[idx]}
                </AccordionContent>
             )}
         </AccordionItem>
    </AccordionItem>
}}
```

How to fix it

```
{m.value.map((firstValue, firstIndex)=>
    <AccordionItem value={m.value[firstIndex]}>
        <AccordionTrigger>{m.name[firstIndex]}</AccordionTrigger>
            {m.contentValue.map((secondValue, secondIndex)=>
                <AccordionContent  key={secondIndex}>
                    {m.contentValue[secondIndex]}
                </AccordionContent>
             )}
         </AccordionItem>
    </AccordionItem>
}}
```

Better code, use the values served by map instead

```
{m.value.map((firstValue, firstIndex)=>
    <AccordionItem value={ firstValue }>
        <AccordionTrigger>{m.name[firstIndex]}</AccordionTrigger>
            {m.contentValue.map((secondValue, secondIndex)=>
                <AccordionContent  key={ secondIndex }>
                    { secondValue }
                </AccordionContent>
             )}
         </AccordionItem>
    </AccordionItem>
}}
```